# What's does the 'downloaded' entry represent from a BitTorrent tracker response?

Tags: php, bittorrent

Example response:

```
Array(4
   complete   =>  3147
   downloaded =>  33
   incomplete =>  71
   name       =>  ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso
)
```

From the [BT specs](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Metainfo_File_Structure) it looks like `complete` refers to the number of seeds and `incomplete` to the number of peers that are downloading.

But what does `downloaded` mean? It appears to change everytime I make a new request, just like complete/incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It represents the number of users who downloaded the file completely and are online

Comment: k.. so this is the actual number of seeds